# Permissions issue: how can Apache access files in my Home directory?

Tags: permissions

I know file permissions have been covered on here before, but im struggling to get my head around the concept for my scenario.

- I created the files on an old ubuntu installation.
- Ive copied the files into my new ubuntu installation and put them in my webroot.
- When i attempt to run the files (theyre PHP files) i get an error relating to permissions

in an attempt to fix this, i assumed that they must still be owned by the previous owner, so i ran `chown -R` on the directory, with my username as an argument, in order to take ownership of all of the files in the directory. It should be noted that the usernames between new and old ubuntu installations were the same.

When i attempt to run the files again, same problem: 500 error due to permissions problems. Can anyone tell me what other steps i should take?

The webroot for my apache installation is inside my home folder. If i create new files in my webroot, they also work as expected, its only the old files that are causing the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that file permissions are copied when the file is, can someone confirm that? Otherwise, would it be possible to give the files to some other user (or root), and then reclaim them?

Comment: Ok, i have solved my problem of the files not executing, but i did it by simply running `chmod -R 777 dir` on the directory in question. I cant help thinking theres a better way of doing it though

Comment: 777 permissions in a file will allow everybody to write your files which may result in damage to your pages or hacking. You should try with 755 which is normally used for php files. Make sure you don't require to enable the "allow execution" for a file, in which case you can run chmod [filename] -x. Information about the chmod command can be reached by clicking the next link: http://catcode.com/teachmod/chmod_cmd.html

Comment: What does the Apache error log show?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The directories above your webroot should have the execute bit set to allow Apache descend into the directories.

If you have your webroot located at `/home/user/htdocs`, the `/`, `/home`, `/home/user` and `/home/user/htdocs` should have the execute bit set.

---

The above solution "works", but it's not ideal. If you've created a folder, Apache cannot write to it. The reverse happens too.

This can be "fixed" by setting umask 0007 and adding yourself to the Apache group (www-data if I'm not mistaken), so that newly created files and folders are writeable by the group.

Alternatively, you can install an alternative Apache MPM: [Apache2 MPM ITK](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/apache2-mpm-itk) ([info on configuring](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/)) and adjust the configuration so Apache runs under your user.

Comment: For explicit instructions on how to accmplish this see Marco's answer [below](http://askubuntu.com/a/64894/31658)

Comment: @hobs Even better, http://askubuntu.com/a/46371/6969

Answer (score 45):

If your server documents are in `/home/$USER/public_html` directory you need to run

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/$USER/public_html
```

to give ownership of the DocumentRoot folder to the user `www-data` and group `www-data`.

Then you can add yourself to the group `www-data`

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```

Finally, you need to make the DocumentRoot folder writable by owner (www-data user) and to your self (as part of the `www-data` group):

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/$USER/public_html
```

For convenience you can make script named `public_html_fix.sh` with content:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo adduser $USER www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/$USER/public_html
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/$USER/public_html
```

Save it inside `/home/$USER/bin` and make it executable using:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/$USER/bin/public_html_fix.sh
```

Then you call it whenever you need, from wherever on the file system you happen to find yourself like this:

```
public_html_fix.sh
```

Comment: worked for me....

Comment: Great Answer! - With Examples and even a convenience script and how to use/install Excellent!

Comment: If this is done on a shared host, how do you stop other users in the `www-data` group reading  your files, or writing to for that matter?

Comment: Really awesome answer ... you saved my life

Comment: `chmod -R 775 /home/$USER/public_html` really terrible. `find /home/$USER/public_html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` and `find /home/$USER/public_html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` is a lot better

Comment: Or `chmod ug+rwX -R .` The big `X` means "propagate executable if it were there".

Comment: Don't we need to work on httpd.conf file? FYI I am using CentOS

Answer (score 1):

Apart from chmoding files and editing apache .conf files, I want to say that nothing worked for me because my files were on a partition that I had auto-mounted via nautilus. This limits the partition for your user only.

To check if your files are visible by `www-root` or whatever user runs apache (run `ps -aux | grep apache2` to check), run the following command:

```
sudo su -l www-data -s /bin/bash
```

and try to read a file from your document root.

If the file is not readable check that:

1) you have set all other file permissions

2) you have used `FollowSymlinks` in your `.conf` files if needed

3) you have set up DocumentRoot

3) mount your partition for all users. I had to edit `/etc/fstab` and specify my partition via its UUID:

```
UUID=afdee1d3-5bb8-4652-892f-e83a9b5ff72e /mnt/4tb      ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,errors=remount-ro
```

Then unmount your partition via nautilus and do a `sudo mount -a`. If all goes well your files are now under `/mnt`. Update your symlinks and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to always set this up is the way VirtualMin does it.

create user and group
"myhome"

Make apache user a member of group "myhome".  Not the other way around like some of the explanations here describe

So now apache has read and execute access to /home/myhome in addition to /home/myhome/www

"myhome" user has write access

Comment: I like this concept, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. User `www-data` belongs to group `myhome`. All files and directories have group write permissions and belong to `myhome:myhome`. I restarted apache. Apache still can't write new files and folders. (PHP script using www-data:www-data user/group)