# Making file in user's homedir accessible from web/webserver

Tags: permissions, apache2, root, symbolic-link

I have a txt-file one of my user's homedir which is regularly updated there by a script.
I now want to be able to access (read) this file from the web.

```
/home/user/folder/file.txt
```

So what I tried now is to log in as root, go into my webservers httpdocs folder

```
/var/www/path/to/domain/httpdocs
```

and there I tried to create a symbolic link with

```
ln -s /home/user/foler/file.txt /var/www/path/to/domain/httpdocs/file.txt
```

But this didn't work... I already tried changing the chmod of the symlink (which changes the ones from the original file of course) and also a chown to the user from webserver, but no matter what I tried I cannot open the file from the web or from a php-script (which is what I want to do)

Can anybody help me and tell me what I need to do? What rights do I need to give? Or is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: can you try `chmod o+r /home/user/folder/file.txt
`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Permissions issue: how can Apache access files in my Home directory?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26848/6969).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbolic link will always have these permissions: lrwxrwxrwx. The "**l**" indicates that it is a link. Therefor, all users can follow the link because the effective permissions are those of the file to which the link points. It is never useful to try changing the permissions of a symbolic link.

The whole path from the root to the file in question must be readable by the Apache user.  So... take a look the permissions of the home folder:

```
ls -la /
```

The home directory should be owned by root, group owned by root, with 0755 permission mask by default: `drwxr-xr-x`. If not, change it:

```
sudo chown root:root /home; sudo chmod 0755 /home
```

Now take a look at your user's directory:

```
ls -la /home
```

If the username in question is *sambo*, the user's home directory should be owned by sambo, group owned by sambo, with 0755 permission mask by default: `drwxr-xr-x`. If not, change it:

```
sudo chown sambo:sambo /home/sambo; sudo chmod 0755 /home/sambo
```

Repeat this as many times as needed, for however many directories exist until you reach the directory that contains the file. Then, don't forget about the file itself.

```
sudo chown sambo:sambo /home/sambo/path/to/file/file.txt; sudo chmod 0644 /home/sambo/path/to/file/file.txt
```

Then use PHP to open it:

```
<?php
    $file = '/home/sambo/path/to/file/file.txt';
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
```

You could use the symbolic link at this point, too.

Comment: Well I've tried that... I set the whole path from home to the directory of the file to chmod 0755 and the file itself too. But still the script cannot read the file nor can I directly open it yet...

Comment: Are you running PHP in safe_mode? (You would have to to chown your file to www-data. 'chown www-data file.txt'). Any errors in Apache log file?

Comment: I went the other way now which worked for me... I had teh script write it directly into the /var/www/... path, but I needed your chmod changes here to have it writable there... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access files from my system with [mediatomb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mediatomb) (see [the documentation](http://mediatomb.cc/pages/documentation)) as it has a web UI. I would recommend enabling password protection at least.

Another alternative is opera unite web server.