# Getting 'permission denied error' with Wget

Tags: wget

I installed the [LAMP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) on my Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) with

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Now I navigate to `/var/www` and use

```
wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.x-dev.tar.gz
```

I get the following error.

```
 --2011-08-03 13:59:00-- 
 http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.x-dev.tar.gz Resolving
 ftp.drupal.org... 64.50.233.100, 64.50.236.52 Connecting to
 ftp.drupal.org|64.50.233.100|:80... connected. HTTP request sent,
 awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 2757101 (2.6M)
 [application/x-gzip] drupal-7.x-dev.tar.gz: Permission denied

 Cannot write to `drupal-7.x-dev.tar.gz' (Permission denied).
```

How do I resolve this error?

I tried to download the same file in the downloads folder, and it went on without an issue. So it seems to be some permission error, but I'm not sure about that or how to solve it.

Comment: Related: [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/q/46331/6969)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you need root permissions to write to /var/www. So you should use **sudo** in front of your command i.e

```
sudo wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.x-dev.tar.gz
```

Comment: this works, but in my desktop, I don't require to use sudo in front of wget

Comment: @Nikhil: you might have changed the permissions of /var/www on your desktop. Its not wget which needs sudo but the directory /var/www as only root user has write permissions to this directory.

Comment: this might be the case, because I just used tar to unpack the files, and it also required me to use sudo, which was not the case with desktop version.

Comment: @Nikhil: tar will unpack the file drupal-7.x-dev.tar.gz and will create few directories and files in the process in /var/www directory. Again as only root has write permissions to /var/www, you need to use sudo to untar the file. If you dont want to use sudo you can either switch to root prompt using "sudo -i" or change the permissions on /var/www directory to allow writes to your username but I WONT RECOMMEND any of these methods. Stick to using sudo, its safer.

Comment: ok, I got it, I also found comment by Lekensteyn helpful. Using sudo all the time is really annoying and painful at times.

Comment: @binW let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/979/discussion-between-nikhil-and-binw)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `sudo` every time you get some error; this does not fix the problem.
The problem is, as the error says that you don't have "permission" to "write" to that directory.

Of course, root has the right to do anything, which the primary goal of many viruses happen to be.
I have `chmod 755` & `chmod 766` to get the same error with `wget`, `cp` & `mv`.

What worked was to own the directory being worked in so don't have to `sudo` often:

```
sudo chown <username> <directory>
```

After this, ordinary commands work normally.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ownership `chown` of the directory and sub directories `-R` fixed the error for me. In ubuntu 20.04 LTS version. I ran the following command and this permission denied error was fixed.

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www`
and
`sudo chown -R www-data. /var/www`