# I am so fresh to Ubuntu and Linux , during my installation of Joomla, I found the following error

Tags: joomla

```
rida@rPC:/var/www/html$ wget https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.3/Joomla_3.4.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip
```

**Output is :**

```
Joomla_3.4.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘Joomla_3.4.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip’ (Success).
```

Comment: also related http://askubuntu.com/questions/205441/how-do-i-set-up-local-joomla-sites-for-web-developing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're in the `/var/www/html` folder, and your user doesn't have permission to write files there.

Change to some folder in your home (for example `cd ~` ) and try again.

Or if you really really want to write to the `/var/www/html` folder, prefix your `wget` command with `sudo`

Or better yet, next time just search for [wget permission denied](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=wget+permission+denied&ia=qa) and you would've found this very very similar answer [Getting 'permission denied error' with Wget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55606/getting-permission-denied-error-with-wget) (and I wouldn't have been bothered typing this ;-)

Comment: You're welcome, actually on the StackExchange sites (like here) selecting an answer as correct (clicking on the check-mark) and/or up-voting (clicking on the up-arrow) is the preferred way to say "thanks" or "that's the answer".  And practice searching for related words, like "joomla ubuntu wget error" or anything similar, and any error messages, it's usually faster too