# How can I get php scripts to run locally in a browser?

Tags: php

I'd like to use php includes to streamline the process of making a few web pages. The problem with that, however, is that I can't seem to test them locally. They work fine on the server, but my computer doesn't seem to understand them. I tried installing php and apache but it didn't seem to work. What do I need to do to set up a php testing server locally?

Comment: Since php is server side scripting you need to get your apache server working with php enabled.

Comment: But by installing the packages `php5` and `apache` this should work out of the box as far as I know.

Comment: Use php includes (`include 'file';`)? Not sure I get that one. If you load localhost in a browser, do you see the generic Apache site? Have you `sudo apt-get install php5`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the package `libapache2-mod-php5` (which will also install the package for the webserver: `apache2`). Files can be put in `/var/www`.

If you then open http://localhost/index.html in your browser, `/var/www/index.html` is displayed.

The default settings are pretty secure, PHP errors are logged to `/var/log/apache2/error_log` and not showed in the browser. To change this on a development machine, edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and change `display_errors = Off` to `display_errors = On`.

Some modules are not installed by default. If you do image processing, you likely need the GD library for PHP, package `php5-gd`. To get a list of all available modules, open a terminal, type `sudo apt-get install php5-` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to get a list.

See also: [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/q/46331/6969)

Comment: How can I change the default path `/var/www/index.html`?

Comment: Have a look at the configuration files in `/etc/apache2/`, specifically the ones in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

Comment: Thanks. Other way is creating a link (I am on Ubuntu): `ln -s /my/location/of/project/`

Answer (score 0):

Install taskel & the LAMP stack

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel

sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

You should now have an apache server with php and mysql.