# webserver folder cannot be accessed without using root

Tags: permissions, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

My webserver folder, called www, cannot be accessed without using root.

Any ideas?

Comment: Kindly refer this post 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Answer (score 0):

If you own the computer, you probably can become a root user.  You can either use sudo to make yourself root for one command or sudo su to make yourself root until you exit (which you probably don't want to do).  The link that siron posted shows some ways that will make it so that you don't have to keep becoming root.