# User has no permissions in sftp

Tags: permissions, ssh, chmod, sftp

I installed LAMP in my Digital Ocean droplet. I have successfully logged in to SFTP.

However, when I try to do anything in my /var/www/html/ folder it says permission denied.

It may be worth mentioning my user has these privileges in `visudo`

```
# User privilege specification
root        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
USERNAME    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Does anyone know what I can do to allow my new user to securely make changes and upload things?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/var/www/html/folder`? To be honest, I've never used `visudo`, but that doesn't mean it isn't a useful tool. If Ubuntu tells you that you don't have permission to access a file or directory, then you don't have permission. You just need the user to be a member of the group for the directory and allow members of the group to edit files in the directory (commonly with `664`).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @Paul. I ended up following [this guy's instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196062/sftp-permission-denied-on-files-owned-by-www-data?rq=1) and it ended up working great!