# How can I give myself permission to edit files in /var/www without having to use the root account or sudo?

Tags: permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Permissions mystify me. I'm worried about compromising the security of my folder, too, since it's public.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To give only your user permission to /var/www. You want to change the group owner to your primary group. If your username is joe this is how you would do it.

```
sudo chgrp joe /var/www
```

You then need to chmod the directory so its writable by the group joe.

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

after that you can write to /var/www

If you want to be able to edit and delete existing files. You need to take ownership of them.

```
sudo chown -R joe /var/www/*
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, but it didn't affect the existing files in /var/www, i.e. I'm still getting "permission denied" when trying to modify anything I have in /var/www. How can I apply these permissions recursively to everything in /var/www?

Comment: for existing files I would take ownership of them. simply do something like sudo chown -R joe /var/www/* . you can in theory just change owner of /var/www to joe and then re-curse down, however I like to keep directories like this owned by root, which means you can not recursively delete the whole directory.