# sshfs no write access

Tags: sshfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

I am trying to use `sshfs` to mount an remote directory so that I can change the files like local. My problem is that i only can read the files.

what I've done:

1. Added my local user `michael` to the fuse group
2. Added my local user `root` to the fuse group
3. Mounted the directory: `sshfs -o idmap=user michael.t@server:/var/www/ www`

I can read the files but not write.

I cant logon with root directly, so I have always to logon with my user and then make `sudo su`. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Michael, the problem you are encountering are remote, not local. If you can read a file using sshfs, but not write it, you are missing permissions on the remote side. See the linked duplicate question.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: that question is not a duplicate, it doesn't mention sshfs at all. Related questions aren't duplicates.