# Cannot create a new document in /var/www

Tags: permissions, sudo, webserver

I'm unable to create a new document in /var/www/

I followed this tutorial :- [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371)

and did as suggested, but still I'm unable to make a new document.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need root permissions to write to /var/www folder. You can create/edit files in /var/www folder with sudo.

```
sudo gedit /var/www/myfile.html
```

or

```
sudo touch /var/www/myfile.html  # only to create a file.
```

**Additionally,**

You can choose one of your own directory as your web folder. You can create a folder in your /home directory and change the web server's folder to it.

you can replace "/var/www" string in following files into your own directory path and then you can use new directory as your www folder.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
```

After changing contents of the above files, run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

to restart webserver. Then you will be able to use new directory as the web folder.