# ./opt/lampp folder & file editing help

Tags: command-line, permissions, apache2

I installed XAMPP but I need to edit folders and files in there. I did the following

```
groupadd lampp
usermod -a -G lampp kyle
chown -R root:www-pub /var/www 
chmod 2775 /opt/lampp 
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

(Above code from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var))
So ya, I logged out then back in and nothing changed. So ya any help would be awesome
Thanks  - FRED

Answer (score 0):

you need to add yourself to the `www-pub` group

plus `/opt/lamp` is not the same as `/var/www`

```
sudo groupadd www-pub #I am not sure if you need this
sudo usermod -a -G www-pub kyle
sudo chown -R root:www-pub /var/www 
sudo chown -R root:www-pub /opt/lamp
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
sudo find /opt/lamp -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
sudo find /opt/lamp -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

BUT you probably need EITHER /opt/lamp or /var/www , not both

Then log out and back in.

See also [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Comment: Can elaborate? The answer is in the LQP queue.

Comment: oh XD i didn't write it right :P I still need a way for me to edit /opt/lampp

Comment: After you run the above commands, log out and back in.