# How to change the destiny owner on a bind mounting point

Tags: mount, permissions

```
sudo mount -o user=www-data,group=www-data --bind /home/chachan/workspace/ /var/www
sudo mount -o owner=www-data,group=www-data --bind /home/chachan/workspace/ /var/www
chachan@magento:~$ sshfs chachan@192.168.56.1:/home/chachan/workspace/magento /home/chachan/workspace
chachan@magento:~$ sudo mount -o owner=www-data,group=www-data --bind /home/chachan/workspace/ /var/www
chachan@magento:~$ ls -lh /var/www
total 700K
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 2.8K Nov 26 10:44 api.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 app
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 2.8K Nov 26 10:44 cron.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan  717 Nov 26 10:44 cron.sh
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 downloader
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 errors
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 1.2K Nov 26 10:44 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 5.9K Nov 26 10:44 get.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 includes
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 2.6K Nov 26 10:44 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 2.4K Nov 26 10:44 index.php.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 6.3K Nov 26 10:44 install.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 js
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan  11K Nov 26 10:44 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan  11K Nov 26 10:44 LICENSE.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan  11K Nov 26 10:44 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 1.3K Nov 26 10:44 mage
drwxr-xrwx 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Mar 31 09:33 media
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan  886 Nov 26 10:44 php.ini.sample
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 pkginfo
-rw-r--r-- 1 chachan chachan 572K Nov 26 10:44 RELEASE_NOTES.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 shell
drwxr-xr-x 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 skin
drwxr-xrwx 1 chachan chachan 4.0K Nov 26 10:44 var
```

I want to have `www-data:www-data` as owner:group in the above list of files.

Any idea what am I missing or doing wrong?.

Thanks

Comment: You can not change ownership with `mount --bind`, see http://superuser.com/questions/623375/mounting-directories-with-bind-different-permissions . In addition, your user case is made even more complex bu your use of sshfs. I suggest you see http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Answer (score 1):

I fixed adding `uid`, `gid` and `allow_another` options for sshfs. Like this:

```
sshfs -o uid=33,gid=33,allow_another chachan@192.168.56.1:/home/chachan/workspace/magento /home/chachan/workspace
```

I also added (uncomment) `user_allow_other` option to `/etc/fuse.conf` and it's working smoothly :)