# Giving ownership of the directory to the apache user?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on LAMP. 
As I am new one to Ubuntu. So, I Used this online tutorial 
[How to install wordpress on ubuntu manually](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-12-04)

But when I am trying to give ownership of the directory to the apache user it's not working
I am giving the following commands

```
sudo chown admin:www-data /var/www -R 
sudo chmod g+w /var/www -R
```

"admin" is the name which I choose for my wordpress database user.
Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: For OS X I've used [this command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39352849/1330787).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do not use the database user as the UNIX user. Use `www-data`.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

There is a difference between the database user and the Apache user. The Apache User is the only one who can actually read the files. The database user is only meant for giving/taking database read/write permissions.

In addition, keep the default permissions from the webapp install. Do not change those, except for the owning user/group. If you are instructed by the webapp, change permissions.

---

If you are more concerned about security, you could instead run the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 640 /var/www
```

This makes the actual files owned by your user, so that only you (and root) can modify them. The reason `www-data` is referenced is so that Apache can still READ the files, but not actually write to them.

The `640` allows you (the file owner) to read and write, while allowing the `www-data` group to read files. It also blocks anyone else from possibly reading the file contents.

(The above is only one possible (*untested*) method. More good ways are available [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/208574))

Comment: Just be aware that that is not the most secure option. See the link I gave above for details.