# New files not inheriting permissions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2, webserver

To start,

Everytime I upload a file to my apache web server, the file is not useable by the server due to it's permissions being denied. As a developer this is very frustrating because I do not want to run `sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www` everytime I upload a file.

Since I do not have access to tune2fs or 'mount' on my VPS, ACL is out of the question. I have been trying to use the following post, however no luck.

**Post:** http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900844

Anyone have any ideas on how every new file can inherit the parent's permissions?

Comment: 1. Set setgid on the directory. http://askubuntu.com/q/46331/158442 2. Set umask for Apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user