# Apache2 Virtual host: granting permission

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I am creating virtual host on Ubuntu 14 LTS. They are working fine but I cannot grant permissions to my user.
I tried the command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/test.com/public_html
```

But I got the following:

```
chown: invalid group: 'admin:admin'
```

admin is my user I created to log with the ssh on my server.
I am asking because as it is I cannot transfer file using filezilla (I log as admin).
Any ideas?

additional info

```
id -g
100

groups
users sudo
```

Comment: That would mean there's no `admin` group. Edit your post to include the output of `id -g` or `groups`. Also, if this is a folder for a website, consider setting the group to `www-data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you have it. Your primary group is not `admin`, but `users` (GID 100).

You can either:

- leave the group empty (to use your primary group)
- Use the `id` command to obtain your primary group or GID
- or, as I suggested earlier, use `www-data` as the group, especially if you want the web server to be able to write to that directory. This is what I would recommend. See [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371)

In order:

```
sudo chown $USER: ...
sudo chown $USER:$(id -gn) ...
sudo chown $USER:$(id -g) ...
sudo chown $USER:www-data ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I am currently trying to understand what is the www-data group

Comment: @Raphael_b it's the primary group of the `www-data` user, and Apache processes on Ubuntu usually run as `www-data`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371

Comment: just a quick 'stupid' question. On your answer when you put '...' what do the dots means?

Comment: @Raphael_b They're [ellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). I used those to mean whatever you'd want to put in the `chmod` command after that, such as other options, paths, etc.

Comment: after some work I succeeded in using www-data as a group to my virtual hosts. Thanks a lot for your help!