# How to host server on local PC(ubuntu) and set up virtual hosts

Tags: server, apache2, 14.10

I am new to Ubuntu and I wanted to host a server on it.

I googled a bit and read something about Apache and IIS and I couldn't get much out of it.  Right now I am confused about how to proceed.

What I want to do is

- Host server on local PC and set up virtual hosts on same PC
- in virtual host, have “myname.com” opened in browser

Any relevant links which could serve as a tutorial?

Sorry if it has been already asked, it would be kind of you if you could redirect to that thread.

Comment: The LTS server guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: So I have to use apache to do the things if I am not wrong?

Comment: Depends on what you intend to do. For many things Apache is more commonly used and so you'll find more documentation. nginx is also an option. IIS is Windows-only, no help for that here.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. What I meant was, will I be able to complete the stated tasks with apache? Sorry for my ignorance, but I am a complete newbie

Comment: Yes. Both Apache and nginx can do that.

Comment: Can you point me to some good introductory tutorials on apache. I googled it but I am not sure on which one to go with?

Comment: I'll write on here, but it will take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two most common tools for this are the Apache and nginx servers.

---

Notes:

- You'll need to edit a few system configuration files. If you're uncomfortable with `vim`, replace `vim` with `nano`, or `gedit` in the following commands. For example, `sudo vim` will become `sudo -H gedit` or `sudo nano`.
- Once you're done setting it up, have a look at [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/)
- A more detailed guide is available from the [Ubuntu LTS Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).

---

## Apache

First, install Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

The Apache configuration files are located in `/etc/apache2`. You'll typically be interested in:

- `/etc/apache2/sites-available` - contains the Virtual Host definitions. Definitions are enabled and disabled using the `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` commands. The enabled site definitions are linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.
- `/etc/apache2/conf-available` - contains custom configuration files. They are enabled and disabled using the `a2enconf` and `a2disconf` commands. The enabled site configuration files are linked to `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`.
- `/var/www/html` - the default directory that Apache serves.

For most instructions, I'll assume we are in `/etc/apache2`.

### VirtualHost setup

Let us create a new site. There's a default configuration available in `sites-enabled/default.conf`. We will make a copy of this, and work on it:

```
sudo cp sites-available/000-default.conf sites-available/my-name.conf
sudo vim sites-available/my-name.conf
```

Change the `ServerName`, so that it uses, for example, `myname.com`:

```
ServerName myname.com
```

Change the `DocumentRoot`, so that it uses, for example, `/var/www/my-name`:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/my-name
```

Save the file, and enable it:

```
sudo a2ensite my-site
```

Now, we need to set up the directory for the site:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/my-name
```

We'll set permissions for convenience:

```
sudo chown $USER:www-data /var/www/my-name
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/my-name
```

Add a few HTML files here.

Since the virtual host is to run locally, we need to map `myname.com` to a local address. To do this, we need to edit `/etc/hosts`:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Add a line like so:

```
127.0.0.2 myname.com myname
```

Save, and then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now, you can browse to `http://myname.com` or `http://myname`, and the contents of `/var/www/my-name` will be displayed.

Comment: Hey @muru. I think I did something wrong, I have asked another question here. Can you help me [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/589653/virtual-host-showing-error-11001-even-after-chown-and-chmod)