# Virtual Host showing error 11001 even after chown and chmod

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, apache2, configuration

I am trying to create a virtual host to just test a basic html website.

Guest OS - Ubuntu 14.04
Host OS - Ubuntu 14.10

In the Host OS, I connect through a proxy server which requires me to enter a user ID and password. I have a bridged network in the guest OS and I am able to connect to the internet in it.

So far I have done these steps.

**1)** Created the `.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`by doing this 
`sudo cp 000-default.conf tasdikr-1081310234.conf`

Then I edited it by `sudo gedit tasdikr-1081310234.conf` to something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#---------- Changes made -------------------

ServerName www.tasdikr-1081310234.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@tasdikr-1081310234.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
ServerAlias tasdikr-1081310234.com

#---------- Changes made -------------------

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

**2)** Made the directory through this

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
sudo chown $USER:www-data /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
sudo gedit /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234/index.html
```

Inside `index.html` I did something like this

```
<html>
  Welcome to tasdikr-1081310234.com!
</html>
```

**3)** After that I changes the`hosts` file in `/etc/hosts`

and after changing it looked something like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   tasdik

#---adding lines for my website---

127.0.0.2   www.tasdikr-1081310234.com  tasdikr-1081310234

#--------adding stuff done--------

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**4)** After that I added my site by running

```
sudo a2ensite tasdikr-1081310234
```

And restarted apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It gave me a message like this

```
* Restarting web server apache2 
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
domain name,using         
127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
                                                                            [ OK ]
```

**5)**  I entered the url `http://tasdikr-1081310234.com` and

`http://tasdikr-1081310234` but I keep getting the error `Error Code 11004: Host not found`

PS : I also tried changing the modes. So I tried

- `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`
- `sudo chmod -R 754 /var/www`
- `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

But it is still giving me the same error.

Any help guys? I have been banging my head on this for the past 2 days.

I have also referred this [Digital ocean - How to set up virtual hosts in ubuntu 14.10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` do not match the URLs you tried to open:
`http://tasdikr-1081310234.com` and `http://tasdikr-1081310234`. Try opening `http://www.tasdikr-1081310234.com`.

Comment: Gives the same error :/