# file readable and writeable by the web server

Tags: apache2, php, webserver

I am try to make a file readable and writable by apache web server.
I have use the following command:

```
sudo chgrp apache /var/www/html/itdb/data/itdb.db
```

When I try to run the php application I get the message:

```
var/www/html/itdb is not writeable by apache
make /var/www/html/itdb/data/files/ writeable by the user running the web server
in unix:

chown www-data /var/www/html/itdb/data/files/; chmod u+w /var/www/html/itdb/data/files/
```

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu ? Ubuntu does not have an apache group.

Comment: yes,  I am using ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu uses www-data . Your web files should be rw by www-data, either as owner or group.See http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Answer (score 0):

in your attempt:

```
sudo chgrp apache /var/www/html/itdb/data/itdb.db
```

you're setting group "apache" as owner of this resource

```
/var/www/html/itdb/data/itdb.db
```

and script is complaining:

```
var/www/html/itdb is not writeable by apache
```

and even giving you solution:

```
chown www-data /var/www/html/itdb/data/files/; chmod u+w /var/www/html/itdb/data/files/
```

(probably you might want to run those with sudo to ensure success)

Good luck

Comment: What you say i true for Ubuntu. As the OP did not get an error when using the apache group they may not be using Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks. However, when I try to run the php web application http://localhost/itdb/  still get the same message

Comment: This is the link to the application i am trying to install                  www.sivann.gr/software/itdb/

Comment: you need to set permissions for the directories a well. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www