# Dynamically set user groups for directories and files on a directory

Tags: permissions, filesystem, users, user-management, groups

I have made some vhosts which resides on my home folder, and i have given the group access to www-data user. This way the project (a web system) renders on the browser.

This is a symfony based project, so that when i run some console commands some files may be created, but unfortunately it will have my user account as the group account. How can i dynamically change the owner (group owner) of that particular directory, so that on creation of every file: its ownership is set as :

```
user:www-data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `setgid` sticky bit on the directory to ensure that all new files in the directory will have their group set to the group of the directory.

To do that, run `chmod g+s DIRECTORY`, where DIRECTORY is the name of your directory.

Comment: @kisanme, Give him/her an upvote. ;)

Comment: @A.B. i don't have enough reputation to do so. But i awfully wanted to.... :(