# Automatic chown and chmod

Tags: permissions, chmod, shared-folders, chown

Does anyone know about inherited file permissions here? I want files/folders moved into a shared folder to automatically change to a set owner/group with set permissions, regardless of which user has moved them.

I’m having trouble with files & folders keeping previous permissions/ owners when they are moved into the shared folder.

Many thanks for any help received!

Comment: I think you will have to make a script or function to do that

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past. I did not properly solve it, but a cronjob with a 5 min. delay does wonders.  (And before someone calls this an ungly workaround: they are right.)

Comment: The *classical* way to do this would be to let the owner remain as-is, but change the group using the directory's `setgid` bit - see for example [Dynamically set user groups for directories and files on a directory](http://askubuntu.com/a/608036/178692)

Answer (score 0):

I've used inotify to kick off a batch file for similar situations with success.

There are some good [examples here](https://techarena51.com/index.php/inotify-tools-example/):