# Set up a folder to automatically set owner and group when new files are created

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm the local user on a system with admin rights. I would like to change the way the default owner and group permissions are set, when new files are created in the specified folder /var/www/html/somefolder

I can for example, run `sudo chown -R leon:www-data somefolder`, but if I create any new files in this folder, they are going to default to `leon:leon`.

Is there something I can do to the folder that will set any files or folder permissions created by me in /var/www/html/somefolder to be automatically set to `leon:www-data`?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use `setgid` on the folder: see for example [Dynamically set user groups for directories and files on a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608031/dynamically-set-user-groups-for-directories-and-files-on-a-directory)

Comment: From a learning point of view using the command `setfacl -d` would have been what I would have done but the `g+s` is shorter, so my question  is there a difference between the two commands @steeldriver

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I don't really know enough about ACLs to comment - sorry

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.