# Permissions when installing brackets.io

Tags: permissions

I recently installed the brackets editor and was wondering what the best approach to handling the file permissions is.

I tend to edit php/html files that are located in my `/var/www/html`
and I'm running into permission problems when I'm not running brackets with `sudo`

I wondered if there is a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

this actually answered my question just fine, the most upvoted answer is perfect:
[How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)