# Allow users in the "exampleuser" group to run su -c exampleuser

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to modify `sudoers` so that users in the group `www-data` can switch to the user `www-data` without a password. I know it is possible, but I don't want to break my system. Here's what I have so far:

```
%www-data: ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u www-data
```

But I am not sure this will work. My purpose in doing this is to let the permissions in `/var/www/` remain `755` and yet allow the group to make changes. Otherwise Drupal and other CMS systems send out warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule should actually be:

```
%www-data ALL = (www-data) NOPASSWD: *
```

The specification in the brackets (`Runas` in `sudoers`) is to specify the target user (and/or group) (the one you specify using `-u`).

That said, what you should actually be doing is setting correct permissions, including the setgid bit. [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)