# edit file with sudo

Tags: command-line, permissions

**if i'm not owner**

i'm using visual studio editor

i can't change the code in any file in `/var/www/html/`

because of this command

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

i need to know how can i be able to change the files

```
sudo -Rf chown www-data:username /var/www/html/

sudo chmod -Rf 775 /var/www/html/
```

those lines can help !?

Comment: Add yourself to a group that this file belongs to , change permissions to 775 , and you should be able to edit it without sudo

Comment: see edit :) ,,,,,

Comment: @Serg could you please elaborate that and post it as an answer? Including the `usermod` command to add the user to the group www-data .

Comment: @Jos I'm on mobile. I can post later or if you wish you can post that yourself.  I don't mind

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/var/www/html` is owned by user `www-data` and group `www-data`. So, as suggested by @Serg, the solution is to add yourself to the group that owns this file, in this case: the group `www-data`:

`sudo usermod -G www-data username`

Then, change permissions of the directory to 775:

`chmod -R 775 /var/www/html`

and you should be able to edit the file.

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: 1- sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data  2- 
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www ....
these commands solved the problem thanks all :)