# Granting write permissions to a group to www folder in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, apache2, users

I am setting up a webserver with Ubuntu 14.04. I have created a group called `webadmins` and added relevant users to this group, I also included `www-data` user as member of this group.

Now I need to give write access `webadmins` group members. Could you give me the command for this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Answer (score 1):

First you must make the directory owned by webadmins

```
sudo chown username:groupname /path/to/directory (-R , optional, recursive)
```

So there are a few ways to do this, but to Just change the groups permissions the easiest is

```
sudo chmod g=w /path/to/directory (-R , optional, recursive)
```

this will make it ONLY have write permissions tho, so you'd probably want

g=rw

If you plan on using linux, you need to learn about chown and chmod, watch some youtube short videos and read some wiki's.

Comment: Yes I got some distance with youtube videos however I couldn't find the way to achieve my request. I just tryed your commands they did not work either. I confirm that ***www-data*** and ***user1*** is member of ***webadmis*** group however only one of the account able to write to /var/www/html folder.