# CHMOD file/folder permissions for LAMP

Tags: lamp

My php project reported error: unable to write file. I found that might be caused by permission guaranteed for directory containing my project files.

I did this:

```
sudo chown [username]:[username] -R [directory location]
```

and then restarted apache but nothing got changed even my **/WWW is in home**. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your project is expecting your files to have a name. Question: is that name the same as your username? If not you need to change your files to -that- name and not your username. And follow muru's link :)

Comment: Anyway, you should not change owner of vhost root directory to your user. It's normally of `www-data`.

Comment: @TungTran always show changing permission not permitted

Comment: OK I've left an answer. See if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that solution got fixed but only working for default /var/www directory:
[How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/$USER/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/$USER/www
```

Then add your user account to www-data group

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```