# How to change index.html file in apache from normal user when apache is installed in root?

Tags: permissions, apache2, restricted-access

I work in Ubuntu 14.04. Well, I always had the misconception that installing a software from the root user makes the software available to all users. So, I wanted to install apache and add my html pages over there. I installed apache using root user. It installed successfully.

Then to test apache, I typed `localhost`, and the default page came up successfully. So then I thought about changing the `index.html` page and adding my code. I was making all my `.html` files in gedit, and thus tried to change `index.html` in gedit. When I tried to open it, it told me I could open it in only read-only mode, and I could not change it. Then I figured out that I could not change the permissions, nor change the file in the normal user.

I thought about it for a while, and thought removing the `index.html` file and adding my on file would work. But it didn't.

Then I uninstalled apache and re-installed it from normal user. Still I couldn't change the `index.html` in normal user.

So is there a way, to access and change the `index.html` file of apache installed in root in normal user?

**NOTE:** I know the password of root, and can even uninstall apache and install it again. This is on my personal computer.

Comment: I highly recommend checking the following question: [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/a/46371/8698)

Comment: If that question doesn't answer your problem, can you add what doesn't work? Also, when you said `Then I uninstalled apache and re-installed it from normal user`, how did you install apache in this case? Because if you were installing it with `apt-get`, it cannot be done without root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
ls -l in the directory where index.html
```

is residing

Find out the file permissions for that.

You could very well done this

```
sudo gedit index.html
```

make the change and it will work

You need to make use of the command

```
chown ashish:ashish or
chown ashish:root
```

to change the onwership of the files in that directory

Comment: You [shouldn't](http://askubuntu.com/a/270019/8698) run gui apps with `sudo`