# Setting up a local Web Server Apache + Text editor

Tags: apache2, atom

I am a new Linux/Ubuntu user and I'm trying to set up an easy local Web Development Server. 
For now I just need Apache. I don't want a LAMP bundle (Like XAMPP - I have a 32-bit architecture) and I don't need PHP and MySQL for now.

I like to do things from scratch and the terminal way. So far I have installed apache. Localhost or 127.0.0.1 runs fine and I have added some files to the root directory `/var/www/html`. I could create a sub-category and an `index.html` file under `/var/www/html` (every time I did, I had to use `sudo` to do that, even though I was signed in as root.)

I also installed Atom as a Text Editor, but Atom can't save my files due to some access restrictions/permissions. Every time I solve an issue another problem occurs. What should I do now?

So much to know about Linux, so much to configure there, my brain is tired of googling and searching for answers that do not really much my questions. I think I need some help here.

Comment: Hi Artskee, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What exactly is the problem you're getting? Is it Atom not saving your files under /var/www/html?

Comment: Yes, I have created a sub-directory var/www/html/test and inside index.html. I have run Atom to edit the index.html but it won't let me to save

Comment: And you're logged in as root?

Comment: I think I am. I am the only user while installing Ubuntu on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad idea to log in as root. Instead, you should use `sudo`.

(Note: normally you can't use `su root` to become root since Ubuntu locks the root account by default.)

Try launching Atom from the command-line with `gksudo atom` (`gksudo` is the equivalent of `sudo` for GUI programs, if you don't have it just running `sudo` should also work). This should allow you to save to /var/www/html without any problems.

However, since saving to the wrong file could mess up your system, it's a bad idea to use `sudo` all the time. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/402861) has some guides on how to avoid using sudo in /var/www/html/ (after which launching Atom normally should work just fine).

Comment: Beacuse  gksudo is not installed I have tried `sudo atom`, that run Atom  with the privileges. I am now able to create and edit files. Do I have always to start atom from the CLI using sudo? opening it through the search bar would be easier and quicker (I will have a look at your link).

Comment: @Artskee As long as you don't have the proper permissions in /var/www/html, yes. However, if you follow the guide in my post above, it will give you the necessary permissions and then you can open it from the search bar.