# Web Server on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, server

While completing some exercises from a book on HTML5, I reached a chapter about installing a server to test-drive web applications. The problem is the book just assumes all users of Linux distros know which and how to set-up servers on their machines. The author also claims that Linux distros may have Apache installed by default.

Is this the case with Ubuntu 16.04? If so, how do I access it to test-drive my web apps? If not, what alternative do I have?

Comment: apache is not installed by default, but I do believe it is available in the repos, do you have the universe repository enabled?

Comment: While LAMP might be overkill, it's easy to set up. Also see: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html, https://askubuntu.com/q/46331/158442

Comment: @muru Isn't the op asking only about apache?

Comment: Yes he is, but he's also new and LAMP is easy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you keep things simple. You can install Apache2; MySQL; PHP and all the required dependencies with a single command.

**Installation**

From your terminal, type:

`sudo apt install lamp-server^`

If you have `sudo` rights, you'll then be prompted for your password. Enter your password, and apt will pull together a list of required dependencies.

It will then ask you if you would like to confirm the installation of these packages.

Press the <kbd>Y</kbd>, then the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

During the installation of the packages, you will see your screen change to something like this:

[image]

Enter a new `root` password for MySQL. This is the MySQL administrator password that you will use for making adjustments to databases and user permissions.

You'll be prompted again:

[image]

Enter your new root password again, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Completion**

This will install and start Apache2; MySQL and PHP 7.

The root directory for your website will be:

`/var/www/html`

You can put your files in this directory, and the web address will be:

`http://<ip address of server>/`

**Notes**

Remember, that there is already an `index.html` inside the `/var/www/html` that you will probably need to replace or remove.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed write-up. Got me up and running immediately.

Comment: +1 most useful for beginners like me !!

Answer (score 1):

Matt, as you've asked about alternatives for test-driving your web apps, you can simply use Python's built-in web server called with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. This works very well for basic needs.

I mention this because, unless there's a need for specific Apache features, you can skip the install of the LAMP stack entirely, as Ubuntu 16.04 already has Python installed, which gets you SimpleHTTPServer with zero installation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

LAMP stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP.
Since I assume you only want to run a simple website, you don't need MySQL or PHP.

Or, if you don't need to open it to the outside world, you could try something even easier and simpler like [livereload](https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a webserver you can use the built-in webserver for Python for example, richbl, mentioned it already, PHP built-in webserver or even NodeJS webserver which are pretty easy to install.

Honestly, my advice, don't install such tools directly on your system. You can better use Vagrant to do that. You can use for example [ScothBox](https://box.scotch.io/) from sctoch.io which comes with dozens of pre-installed tools for web development.

The only thing you need to do is installing Virtual Box on your system and then downloading that scotch box. The benefit of using such a solution is really remarkable because if you mess up with configuration or anything else related to the webserver, you can easily do a `vagrant destroy` and then everything will be deleted (remember don't forget to backup your files from /var/www before doing that). And then doing `vagrant up` for a new scotch box after downloading it from the internet.

Maybe it will be a little bit difficult to get the whole idea of vagrant and vagrant boxes, but believe me it's really handy to have such environment for developing. The big benefit is keeping you OS really clean  from messy web development tools because you don't need to have Apache running all the time on your OS while you will need it just once or twice.