# How to change terminal from ~ to /

Tags: command-line

I do not know what `~$` or `/$` mean in terminal. But, I really need to change my terminal from `~` to `/`. To change a folder permission, for putting a php file in `var/www/html`. Maybe there is an easy way to change `~` to `/` in terminal.

Comment: ~ is short hand for /home/your_user . This has nothing to do with "putting php file in var/www/html" See https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Comment: i can't saved file in the folder /html, so that i will make the permission be writable but the terminal is into ~ not /

Comment: @M.Faire just do `cd /`

Answer (score 3):

I can see you are both new and frustrated.

By default when you open a terminal or log in you will be in your home directory, /home/your_user_name, or ~ for short.

You can always return with `cd ~`

You can change directories with the `cd` command, for example, `cd /` or what have you.

Understand the difference between relative and absolute directories.

From home, or ~ you can cd into documents with the relative path

```
cd Documents
```

or absolute path

```
cd /home/your_user/Documents
```

or with ~

```
cd ~/Documents
```

but you are asking about system files or things outside $HOME. For that you typically need root powers.

BUT for /var/www/html see the link I gave you : [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

For additional information see :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

This is also a very helpful resource: https://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/linuxcommand/TLCL/16.07/TLCL-16.07.pdf

dont be overwhelmed by the length of the document, it goes fast, and you may need to read only the first chapter or two.