# Setting up a collaboration website and can't seem to get the permissions right

Tags: permissions, ssh, webserver, sftp

The end goal is the have a webpage that several people can work on in there spare time.  I made a directory /WEBSITE/public_html and want the main page to be here for several contributors to be able to access.  Made a user group called webadmin and added the users to the group.  then did chown -R mainuser:webadmin /WEBSITE
then I did chown -R mainuser:webadmin /WEBSITE/public_html.  I want to be able to SFTP to in the server and send the website I have to it.  I can sftp in but it will not allow me to send files there.  What am I missing?  I know this is a super noob question so thank you for you time and patients.

DrClaw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Comment: Add each user you wish to be able to edit your web files a member of www-data . I also highly suggest you continue to use /var/www/html as the default location as there is really no need for apache to be crawling outside it's box. Your problem is apach runs as www-data and you have excluded that user (www-data) from accessing files owend by "mainuser:webadmin"

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the directory permissions are correct:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/linux-file-and-directory-permissions/

> Directory permissions
>
> Permissions for directories aren't exactly the same as they are for
>   files. Here are some typical permissions required on directories:
>
> ```
> Execute permission is required for a user to cd into a directory.
> Read permission is required for a user to use a command such as ls to view the files contained in a directory.
> Execute-only permission allows a user to access the files in a directory as long as the user knows the names of the files in the directory, and the user is allowed to read the files.
> Write permission allows the user to create, delete, or modify any files or subdirectories, even if the file or subdirectory is owned by another user
> ```