# Run Apache as separate User and Group

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2

I'm having a little trouble understanding the recommendation to setup a separate user for the file permissions of www/html folder in apache. See point 5 from [this](https://www.tecmint.com/apache-security-tips)

The recommendation is out of the box Apache sets your `html` folder to nobody or daemon. But this isn't a good idea!

I have a VM on [Google Cloud compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) and when uploading files it only lets you do this to your home folder. Then from their with ssh I can move them over to my html folder.

When I do a `ls -a` on my html folder after the move, it has kept the username for my local machine that I uploaded the files and folders from.

Long story short have I, albeit without knowing, basically adhered to this above recommendation? Or do I need to create a completely new user on the box and assign the html folder to that user?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu (and most distros) Apache already runs as a separate user. Various distros use various users, but Ubuntu uses `www-data`.

To manage your web server without root see [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Although the information on that site is helpful, you should always start with the Ubuntu information first wherever possible (IMHO)

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: thanks for the advice, one thing I've noticed though is the www folder itself user is root, then everything inside it has a different user. Should the www not also be a separate user to root?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www . Personally I keep everything on my web server owned by root , group www-data and www-data has ro as much as possible.