# How do I properly make a symlink for /var/www/html while keeping both security and function in mind

Tags: permissions, apache2

I am engaged in a self guided learning project (not school) to simulate a web development environment.
Here is system information:

LAMP  server running in VMWare WorkStation Player on Windows 7 host

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache server 2.4.18
- MySQL 5.7
- PHP 7.0.22
- fstp via Filezilla

When transferring files from Windows, I cannot transfer directly to the document root (`/var/www/html`). For organization reasons I have created sub-directories and files under the html directory. I must use an intermediate folder, which I call `transfers`, and then copy the file via the terminal. Because I am in a learning process, I wish to employ both best practices and efficiency.

Can I set appropriate permissions in the target directory and then create a symlink, or will permissions in the target directory's parent directories negate using this mind set? Any how/why explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. That is the hard way to do things. As a new user, please read the ubuntu documentation before you try to solve problems yourself See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP . Also read about permissions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions . For apache see https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www