# multiple owner of same folder

Tags: 16.04, aws

I have changed owner of the `/var/www/html` folder to `www-data`. Now I want to grant ownership to `ubuntu` as well.

How can I do that? I don't know which group they belong to.
I login to `ssh` by using `ubuntu` username and my FTP is also working with ubuntu, but now due to this change I am facing permission issue when editing a file via ftp.

Comment: Can you try `sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu` and check ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Solution 1

Easiest way if only that one user `ubuntu` and `www-data` need access would be

```
sudo chown ubuntu:www-data <path/to/file or directory>
```

this gives ownership to the user `ubuntu` but still keeps the ownership for the group `www-data`.

So you control what ubuntu can do by

```
sudo chmod u<+|- permission> <path/to/file or directory>
```

and you control what `www-data` can do by

```
sudo chmod g<+|- permission> <path/to/file or directory>
```

or simply use complete permission masks (see example below).

---

**Example**:
User `ubuntu` shall be able to read(`r`), write(`w`), execute(`e`)
`www-data` shall be able read(`r`), execute(`e`) but not write(`w`)
`other users` shall be able to do none of those

```
sudo chmod u+rwx <path/to/file or directory>
sudo chmod g-w+rx <path/to/file or directory>
sudo chmod o-rwx <path/to/file or directory>
```

or using a permission masks ([helpful generator](http://permissions-calculator.org/))

```
sudo chmod 750 <path/to/file or directory>
```

---

Also interresting for your case might be the `-R` parameter for both commands, applying ownership and permissions recursively on the content of a folder.

For more information about options and parameters see
[man chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) and
[man chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

---

---

## Solution 2

I would rather **NOT** add a user to a system functional user's group as suggested in the comments like

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

as this is a really dirty way of granting a user permissions because he could also mess up things...

Instead if you want you could add a completely new group using `groupadd` (see [man groupadd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/groupadd.8.html))

```
groupadd <group name>
```

add all users who shall have the permissions on the file(s) to this group

```
sudo usermod -a -G <group name> ubuntu
sudo usermod -a -G <group name> www-data
```

(for more information see [man usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod))

and now set the ownership of the file(s) to this group

```
sudo chgrp <group name> <path/to/file or directory>
```

than you set the permissions as described before but this time only for the 
group (read(`r`), write(`w`), execute(`e`))

```
sudo chmod g+rwx <path/to/file or directory>
sudo chmod u-rwx <path/to/file or directory>
sudo chmod o-rwx <path/to/file or directory>
```

or using the mask

```
sudo chmod 070 <path/to/file or directory>
```

Note that using this solution you lose the control over the different permissions for `ubuntu` and `www-data`.

Comment: dont take it, it was just my thought, ok. btw, can you mention two words about, why `www-data` shouldnt have `write` permision?

Comment: I have four: It was an example. I only used it to show how the permission flags work. Ofcourse there might be use cases where e.g. the server should be able to write a file as well :)

Comment: thanks! ! last thing - if you could mention two words about `-a` and `-G` flags you used, could have been nice also for novices like me

Comment: and last's last thing:  somewhere i've seen similar solution, but after creating a group, using `gpasswd -a <username> <group name>`. can you elaborate on that as well in post?   and also, how it will be if there needs to be 3rd user, in solution1 ?

Comment: If `www-data` is a user name not a group name, can you still do `sudo chown ubuntu:www-data <path/to/file or directory>`?

Comment: @DamnVegetables no. Most of the times there is an according group for each user though ... wouldn't recommend it though.. rather create according shared group and add the users to them as needed