# Create new ssh user account to access specific folder only

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, php

I have an apache2 server running on ubuntu 16.04, for now everytime i access my project files inside a specific folder i use root user for running php function and edit some files, after i finish i need to run `chown -R www-data:www-data .` inside a terminal, because after i run my php function the file owner will become user:user (root:root). what i need is:

1. Create new user for my server
2. When access my server using ssh this user will be inside a specific folder automatically
3. Grant this user a permission to do anything inside this specific folder

For example, Create a user named **tonya**, when someone access server using user **tonya**  `ssh sonya@server.com`, he will be redirected to **/var/www/specific_folder**, user tonya can do anything inside this folder and when tonya set the php file owner or folder to `tonya:www-data` it will work like when i set the file owner to `www-data:www-data`

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with

```
adduser --home /var/www/specific_folder --shell /bin/bash --no-create-home --ingroup www-data --ingroup ssh tonya
```

- `adduser` is used to add a user
- `--home` specifies home directory which is where the user will be when they log in
- `--shell` is to specify the shell, by default it is usually just `/bin/sh` which is not as user friendly as `/bin/bash`
- `--no-create-home` will not create the home directory so you must use one that already exists
- `--ingroup` adds the user to specified group
- the last argument is the username

You could make the user jailed using this guide:

- [Restrict SSH User Access to Certain Directory Using Chrooted Jail](https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/)

Please remember that even if you jail a user, it is very possible to escape a jail. If you're giving a user access to your system, you may as well be giving them root access because once they have shell access, it's almost always possible to gain root.  Setting up a jail will most likely keep a basic user from doing anything too harmful but will do little to nothing to stop a malicious user from doing harmful stuff.

Comment: why there's 2 ingroup? how can this user get my root access?

Comment: one ingroup for ssh and one for www-data, and I'm not saying that they will be able to get root access but you should never allow a user on your system if you don't trust them because once they have shell access on your system, they're 50% the way to root basically. New exploits are discovered daily and because of that, you can never consider a system to be secure.

Comment: @Desultroy when i change my php file owner from www-data:www-data to tonya:www-data it gives me a file permission error , when i try to access the php from browser

Comment: You should probably change the permissions of the file so that it is group based and not owner based.  I don't know if php requires the execute permission but it definitely needs the read permission.  Permissions can be explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions