# How to add php website files to XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, visual-studio-code

Ubuntu newbie trying to migrate from Windows.

I installed XAMPP, the installer placed the files in /opt/. I am trying to add my own work and after some digging I found that XAMPP serves files from the `htdocs` folder.

When I try to save a php file from VSCode to that directory it fails due to permissions. How do I get around this? Am I missing something, is this how you use XAMPP? I looked on their websites but couldn't find anything which lead me to believe I must be doing something wrong.

I am applying the same approach I used with WAMP on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I ended up setting up a symbolic link using the second solution from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/889558). Thanks @pa4080 for pointing it out.

Comment: Also this (I can't suggest second duplication): [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/566421)

Comment: @pa4080 Thank you. I think the second link is more applicable.

Comment: Hello, please look also the answer of the first suggestion, it uses interesting approach :)