# How to make both users have permission to the same folder?

Tags: server, permissions, nginx, 21.10

In my Laravel app, I am using Nginx as the server.
Ubuntu version is 21.10

I also want to use Laravel's console (Tinker) to log stuff. When I set `www-data` to be the owner of `storage` folder, which contains the logs, then I can view my app via `localhost`, but then I can't use Tinker to log information, for example `Log::debug("test");`, as I get:

```
UnexpectedValueException with message 'The stream or file 
"/var/www/laravel-app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be       
opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

so I set my user temporarily to own `storage` when I want to use Tinker:

`sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage`

But then I can't view my app, as I get the same error as above when trying to access `localhost`.

How can I make both users have permissions to `stoarge`?

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Sorry, added tag for the version and in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Comment: @muru yes, it did help (I used solution #1, the one with `sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data`). Why didn't the solution provided by the answer on this post help? You can see below, using `usermod`, I added both users to the group yet that didn't work, but using `gpasswd` and the other lines did help. Why? and do I need to undo the `usermod` commands I did?

Comment: @Ligonsker I'd guess the paths in question didn't have `r`/`x` permissions for group, which were fixed by the `chmod` commands in that answer. Now the answer here also has a permission-fixing command, so it might work now. No, you don't need to undo the `usermod` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups. Simply add those users to the www-data group

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data user1
sudo usermod -aG www-data user2
```

To ensure that the group has right to read and write:

```
chmod -r ug+rw path_of_folder_containing data
```

The you could check with `ls -la`:

```
-rw-------  1 aUser aGroup         48  2. Apr 20:44  someFile #only user may read/write
-rw-r--r--  1 aUser aGroup         48  2. Apr 20:44  someFile #user r/w, group and others only read
-rw-rw-r--  1 aUser aGroup         48  2. Apr 20:44  someFile #user & group r/w, others only read
```

You should log out and in again so that the group change takes effect.

Comment: I did that, and when using `getent group www-data` I see both users listed, but still, only the one who I did `chown` can operate at a time

Comment: you need to allow those folders/files that goup members may read or write them. See my updated answer. I usually chmod the folder using the recursion flag "-r"