# How to avoid using sudo for newly created files and folders by www-data?

Tags: server, permissions

I've been using the following post for some time to avoid using `sudo`:

[How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

But when I use Laravel to create folders, it's created under group `www-data` and user `www-data`, and then I have to perform all the commands in the post all over, i.e.:

```
sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

It's annoying because the code I'm working on creates many new folders and files.

The server (via the Laravel code) creates folders with the following permissions:

```
drwx--S--- 2 www-data www-data
```

and files with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data
```

In this case, how can I avoid using sudo?

Comment: Is the Apache user required? If the permissions should always be for a user account, perhaps the Apache configuration can be changed to run as that particular user.

Comment: Btw it's nginx, maybe I could try to find a way to do that