# How to allow an FTP user to manage /var/www/site1 which is owned by www-data user

Tags: apache2, ftp, www, proftpd

I have a site called site1 located in **/var/www/site1**, and it is owned by **www-data user**. The group permission is belong **www-data group**.

The web server is **Apache2**. The FTP server is **ProFTPD**.

As we allow FTP for an external user called **externalftpusr** to FTP in.

How do I allow this FTP user to upload/change the file accordingly to this /var/www/site1 ?

So far, we did:

```
sudo chmod -a -G www-data externalftpusr
```

When we upload a file, we have this error on FTP client:
550 index.html: Permission denied

We prefer to keep www-data as user on ownership of the site.

I am appreciated your help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you confirm the command you ran to add the FTP account to `www-data`? The one in your question is incomplete (which could explain why it didn’t work) 

Comment: Sorry :) I modified the command already - chmod. Also when we ran: `grep ^www-data /etc/group` ... we can confirm that **externalftpusr** user on that group.

Comment: When adding a user account to a group, one would generally use `usermod`, as you are **mod**ifying a **user** account. It will also be important to confirm that the permissions on the directory match those of the files, ideally with a `755` or `775` (never use `777`) 

Comment: Probably a misconfiguration of vsftpd.conf please make sure the user has permission to do so

Comment: @matigo - I mean I've added to the right group for that user. Permission for all folders are 0755 whiles files 0644

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava - We're using the ProFTPD server actually - look at the config and nothing really significant for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Comment: The permissions should be 775 to allow the group member user to write, and also you should use setgid to ensure group permissions are inherited when creating new files.

Comment: @muru - Changed that to 775 and the FTP worked Ok for updating/adding/deleting files. Now, the problem is will this 775 be secure? Cause the Apache can execute via www-data group ?!?!  Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Cause the Apache can execute via www-data group" I don't understand what that means. Execute what? Apache is already running as the `www-data` user, and your question says the files are owned by that user so it already has full permissions.

Comment: @muru I thought the Apache running on the www-data group, not on the www-data user? Technically, I can create any user and set the ownership to let's say **site1** user and assign into www-data group.

Comment: Unless you configured it differently, Apache on Ubuntu runs using the `www-data` user by default.

Comment: @muru - sorry you are right. I run this `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and I found www-data as user. For allowing  this **externalftpusr** updating files to via FTP, 775 looks the way to go.