# How do I troubleshoot a local webserver?

Tags: apache2

I had a webserver running at luna.local, it got eaten when I upgraded to 10.10. In trying to restore it, I'm pretty stumped. I'm more stumped by this:

```
[0 amanda@luna ~]$ apache2 -D DUMP_VHOSTS
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

Where is the run user supposed to be set?

in `/etc/apache2/envvars I see:

```
 16 export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
 17 export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

and `ps aux | grep apache` shows apache2 running as www-data:

```
root      1927  0.0  0.2  36216  8804 ?        Ss   07:44   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14307  0.0  0.1  36216  4388 ?        S    14:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14308  0.0  0.1  36544  5148 ?        S    14:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14309  0.0  0.1  36216  4388 ?        S    14:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14310  0.0  0.1  36216  4388 ?        S    14:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14311  0.0  0.1  36216  4388 ?        S    14:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14409  0.0  0.1  36216  4388 ?        S    14:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

So ... what gives?

Wierder: my Virtualhost definition definitely says:

```
  1 <VirtualHost *:80>
  2         ServerName luna.local
  3 
  4         DocumentRoot /home/amanda/Public/luna
  5         <Directory /home/amanda/Public/luna>
  6                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  7                 AllowOverride None
  8                 Order allow,deny
  9                 allow from all
 10         </Directory>
```

But the error log says:

```
[Tue Jun 07 14:25:54 2011] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/amanda/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Tue Jun 07 14:25:54 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 278 to 215 : URL /
```

Why is it not looking all the way into Public/luna?

Comment: ennvars with www-data should be ok.
what is the output of: `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start`?

Comment: Stopping, starting, reloading are fine. " * Starting web server apache2 [ OK ]"

Comment: If I set the variable manually in apache.conf, I get a more meaningful output from `apache2 -D DUMP_VHOSTS`, but my site still doesn't work.

Comment: when you run `sudo apache2 -D DUMP_VHOSTS` you want to run that as `sudo` otherwise you won't be able to switch to the right user

Comment: @Marco Ceppi sudo makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total red herrings everywhere. I moved files from /var/www/luna to ~/Public/luna and my home directory wasn't world executable. Spotting this helped: [Permissions issue: how can Apache access files in my Home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26848/permissions-issue-how-can-apache-access-files-in-my-home-directory/26856#26856)