# Have lampp use PHP code in a directory not under /opt/lampp

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I have my lampp installed in the default `/opt/lampp` directory and the PHP code is in the `htdocs` folder. Now, to edit any of the files I have to use sudo permissions and have to type my password (or use sudo -i) which I do not want to do.

All I want is to know if I can somehow make lampp use the code that is residing in a folder not located under `/opt/lampp/`. I tried giving full path and using a '..' relative path - both did not seem to work.

Or is it okay to do my work in `/opt/lampp/` folder by using sudo all the the time?

Comment: Please refer to [Permissions issue: how can Apache access files in my Home directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26848/permissions-issue-how-can-apache-access-files-in-my-home-directory) for reasons why you are having issues with home directory paths for Apache. As I believe this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi Thanks for adding the lampp tag. I tried to, but, new users are not allowed to create new tags.
My search wasn't effective enough to find that question. Anyways, I have to find out about execute bit and then try the mentioned solution. I will do it and update.

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer your question although I believe using lampp is not a good thing:

Try to use a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Change into your `htdocs` directory and do something like `sudo ln -s /home/<your user name>/Documents/my_website my_website` where `~/Documents/my_website` is a directory in which you can put all your PHP scripts. Make sure this folder exists. This is *now* tested and it works for me.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Answer (score -3):

lampp is the most stupid thing I know. There are dozens of web servers you can install using the package management, for example apache's httpd. All you have to do is install [apache2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apache2) [image: Install apache2] and [php5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/php5) [image: Install php5]. Then do `sudo a2enmod userdir` and `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`. Now you can put all your PHP scripts in `~/public_html/` and access it on `http://localhost/~<your user name>/`

Comment: But LAMPP (XAMPP) has several package versions. I used to install XAMPP to get php-5.2 since ubuntu has updated to php-5.3 and doesn't provide php-5.2 packages.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you use an almost 5 year old version of PHP which no longer gets any security updates.

Comment: Thanks @dAnjou . Apart from that I have to install MySQL(phpMyAdmin too) and so found LAMPP much easier. I should try out what you have mentioned too.