# How to give root access to a wine application

Tags: wine, lamp

I installed Dreamweaver 8 on Kubuntu with Wine, and I've already installed LAMP. Now I'm trying to give Dreamweaver root access to my `var/www/html` directory so I can write some PHP scripts but I can't find any way of doing that—is it possible?

Also is there any other native Linux app that is as good as Dreamweaver (with syntax highlighting)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www) or [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www) (After searching about it--I think we have Dreamweaver alterantives questions already but I'm not sure--you may want to post a separate question to ask about alternatives to Dreamweaver.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK everybody calm down. You are asking to give a kid the nuclear launch codes of all countries to play with them. I recommend—let me rephrase that—I urgently, highly, extremely,  recommend not giving root access to Wine but instead give permission to read and write to the `www` folder.

I suggest a soft link in your home folder to the `www` folder.

```
ln -s /var/www/html /home/USERNAME/www
```

You should now see a `www` folder in your home folder. If you have any permission problems you can follow one of this answers (not at my PC and I hate writing through small phones):

- [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)
- [Permissions issue: how can Apache access files in my Home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26848/permissions-issue-how-can-apache-access-files-in-my-home-directory)
- [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)
- [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777)

Now you can simply point Dreamweaver to the link in there. I would also follow both links provided in the comments by Eliah. They both can help you in other ways.

Comment: No `chown $USER:www-data`?

Comment: Adding to that, I would recommend creating a symlink in your home directory so that you can point Dreamweaver to the directory much easily rather than navigate through Linux's directory.

Comment: i didn't create a symlink but i got it working by adding permissions to the www folder.Thanks

Comment: I would follow the recommendation of @Oxwivi because it helps you navigate better and it gives you better compatibility with Wine since when configured it takes the home folder as the "Document & Settings" as in Windows.